# BDD feature using RSPEC and Capybara seems to not recognize user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara, bdd

I'm having an issue with my Cancel Registration feature for a practice site I'm working on to understand BDD better.

```
describe "Cancel Registration", js: true do
 let!(:user) { User.create(email: email, password: password, password_confirmation: password) }
 let(:email) { 'example@yahoo.com' }
 let(:password) { 'password' }

 before do
  # Sign in
  visit root_path

  within('.navbar') { click_link('Sign in') }
  fill_in 'Email', with: email
  fill_in 'Password', with: password
  click_button 'Sign in'

  # Cancel registration
 end

 it "displays a goodbye message" do
   within('.navbar') { click_link('Profile') }
   click_link 'Cancel my account'
   page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
   expect(page).to have_content("Bye! Your account was successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon.")
 end

 it "does not allow the user to sign in again" do
   within('.navbar') {expect(page).to_not have_link('Profile')}

   expect(page).to have_content("Invalid email or password")
 end
end
```

At the very beginning of the block, this should create an instance of a User so that the remaining specs could be handled correctly, but when the "before" block executes it doesn't recognize a user and does not sign in so the "displays a goodbye message" block cannot find the link "Profile" which is only displayed is a user has signed in.

Here is the actually failure rspec failure:

```
Cancel Registration
 does not allow the user to sign in again
 displays a goodbye message (FAILED - 1)

User Registration
 failure
  displays an error message
  shows the correct navigation links
 success
  displays a welcome message
  shows the correct navigation links

Flash Notices
 can be dismissed by the user

User
 should require email to be set
 should require case sensitive unique value for email

User Sessions
 failure
   displays an error message
   shows the correct navigation links
 success
  displays a welcome message
  shows the correct navigation links

Failures:

 1) Cancel Registration displays a goodbye message
 Failure/Error: within('.navbar') { click_link('Profile') }
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find link "Profile"
 # ./spec/features/cancel_registration_spec.rb:40:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/features/cancel_registration_spec.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Please give me your thoughts and suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Check if you are right about the reason first. So install `gem launchy` and add `save_and_open_page` just before `within('.navbar') { click_link('Profile') }` at the begging of `displays a goodbye message` block.

Comment: so what exactly am i looking for when i save the page?

Comment: what's happening now is that it tries to login using the username and password from the let() commands, but it returns invalid email or password. which should mean that the let!(:user) line is not creating an instance of a user for the spec to run through.

Comment: I had no much time yet to look on it but just try this first:
as for now you have `let!` as first on your `describe` block. Move it to be executed after orhter `let` (in that order: `let(:email)`, then `let(:password)`, and `let!(:user)`as the last one).

Comment: You can check `log/test.log` as well what if the user's data was INSERTed to the db correctly or not.